# Using Optaplanner to solve VRPTW with large number of customers and sophisticated constraints

Tags: optaplanner

I'm developing a solver for a VRPTW problem using the OptaPlanner and I have faced a problem when large number of customers need to be serviced. By the large number I mean up to 10,000 customers. I have tried running a solver for about 48 hours but no feasible solution was ever reached.

I use a highly customized VRPTW domain model that introduces additional planning entity so-called "Workbreak". Workbreaks are like customers but they can have a location that is actually another planning value - because every day a worker can return home or go to the hotel. Workbreaks have fixed time of departure (usually next day morning), and a variable time of arrival (because it depends on the previous entity within a chain). A hard constraint cares about not allowing to "arrive" to the Workbreak after certain point of time. There are other hard constraints too, like:

- multiple service time windows per customer
- every week the last customer in chain must be a special customer "storage space visit" (workers need to gather materials before the next week)
- long jobs management (when a customer needs to be serviced longer than specified time it should be serviced before specific hour of a day)
- max number of jobs per workday
- max total job duration per workday (as worker cannot work longer than specified time)
- a workbreak cannot have a location of a hotel that is too close to worker's home.
- jobs can not be serviced on Sundays

... and many more - there is a total number of 19 hard constrains that have to be applied. There are 3 soft constraints too.

All the aforementioned constraints were initially written as Drools rules, but because of many accumulation-based constraints (max jobs per day, max hours per day, overtime hours per week) the overall speed of the solver (benchmarks) was about 400 step/sec.

At first I thought that solver's speed is too slow to reach a feasible solution in a reasonable time, so I have rewritten all rules into easy score calculator, and it had a decent speed - about 4600 steps/sec. I knew that is will only perform best for a really small number of customers, but I wanted to know if the Drools was the cause of that poor performance. Then I have rewritten all these rules into incremental score calculator (and survived the pain of corrupted score bugs until all of them were successfully fixed). Surprisingly incremental score calculation is a bit slower for a small number of customers, comparing to easy score calculator, but it is not an issue, because overall speed is about 4000 steps/sec - no matter how many entities I have.

The thing that bugs me the most is that above a certain number of customers (problems start at 1000 customers) the solver cannot reach feasible solution. Currently I'm using Late Acceptance and Step Counting algorithms, because they perform really good for this kind of a problem (at least for a less number of customers). I used Simulated Annealing too, but without success, mostly because I could not find good values for algorithm specific parameters.

I have implemented some custom moves too:

- Composite move that changes workbreak's location when sibling entities are changed using other moves like change/swap moves (it helps escaping many score traps, as improving step usually needs at least two moves to be performed in a single step)
- Move factory for better long jobs assignment (it generates moves that tries to put customers with longer service time in the front of a workday chain)
- Workbreak assignment move factory (it generates moves that helps putting workbreaks in proper sequence)

Now I'm scratching my head, and wondering what I should do to diagnose the source of my problem. I suspected that maybe it was hitting a score trap, but I have modified the solver so it saves snapshots of best score each minute. After reading these snapshots I realized that the score was still decreasing. Can the number of hard constraints play the role? I suspect that many moves need to be performed to find out a move that improves the score. The fact is that maybe 48 hours isn't that much for this kind of a problem, and it should make computations a whole week? Unfortunately I have nothing to compare with.

I would like to know how to find out if it is solely a performance problem, or a solver (algorithm, custom moves, hard/soft score) configuration problem.

I really apologize for my bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR but FWIW:

- To scale above 1k locations you need to use [**NearBy selection**](https://www.optaplanner.org/blog/2015/01/27/ScalingVehicleRoutingAndTSPWithNearbySelection.html).
- To scale above 10k locations, **add** [**Partitioned Search**](https://docs.optaplanner.org/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#partitionedSearch) too.

Comment: I have applied all aforementioned suggestions (even snapshot version of move threads support), but with half-luck. Partitioned search does its job quite decent, but a following then local search phase unfortunately makes things worse. Sometimes a single partition result is not feasible because of max working hours limit, and local search phase should solve this, by dispatching some of jobs to other close workers. Unfortunately it looks like the solver is randomly choosing workers just to decrease the hard constraint, ignoring their distance which gives many pointless routes. 1/2

Comment: For me it looks like the solver does not want to break "stabilized" hard constraint score, thus it limits possible moves. I use all built-in moves that operate on chained planning variables and some custom moves too. I suspect however that at some point of time it is very hard to generate a list of moves required to improve the score. I mean simple changing or swapping randomly selected entities (or chains of them) is not enough. It is relatively easy to decrease hard constraint score by randomly changing entities, but the same thing for soft constraint score seems to be very difficult. 2/2

Comment: I'd have to look into detail to figure out the best way forward. Is this an open academic implementation or an enterprise implementation?

Comment: It is an enterprise implementation, but in fact the project just implements what is really required - a problem model and constraints. All other things are interfaces to other services, etc. I think that maybe these "workbreaks" cause problems. They are immovable in entity chains (custom move filter), and customer entities are moved between them. I realize that having workbreaks may limit possible subchain moves, but I have not invented anything else to get rid of them.

Comment: I have a permission to disclose implementation details. What is your preferred way to have a private discussion about them?

Comment: I can't have a private conversation (except if you have a Red Hat Business Automation [subscription](https://www.optaplanner.org/product/services.html)) as that interferes with our business model of professional support. I was asking because if it's open academic research, I sometimes try to go a step further than just giving pointers (if bandwidth allows).

Comment: I understand. I have been thinking more about my case in general, and my problem may be related to some scoring technique pitfalls that I'm not yet aware off. I mean I do not need a specific product help as scoring techniques falls (in my opinion) into general academic knowledge case. Is there any option to discuss constraint solving related cases as a part of an academic conference? Honestly I'm fascinated by the OptaPlanner, but I'm even more fascinated by the field of knowledge it utilizes. I think I analyzed OptaPlanner's source quite good to understand what happens under the hood 1/2

Comment: But the devil is in the detail. I may understand how the program works, and even try to understand some of its algorithms (years ago I tried to implement Karaboga's Artificial Bee Colony algorithm using Delphi), but I have not much experience in score functions. I can fly anywhere to extend my knowledge: conferences, lectures, meetings etc. I recognize you as the most experienced person in this matter (correct me if I am wrong), and I think the whole thing is not about my specific project. It is all about moving the OptaPlanner project forward, which can be done only by cooperation 1/2